# JFreechart: Count each series over an intervals

Tags: count, grid, jfreechart, series

I am trying get the count of each series point over specific areas of my plot. 
The plot is made up of grids (boxes) and I wish to know the count of each of my series points that is present in each of these boxes. I want to get information like (grid 1 had 2 of series 1, 0 of series 2, 3 of series3, 4 of series 5, etc)
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post questions from a single [account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/798705/jpo).

Answer (score 0):

When you have XYItems you can get the bounds of each item:

```
final Collection<ChartEntity> entities =   
  chartpanel.getChartRenderingInfo().getEntityCollection().getEntities();
for (final ChartEntity e : entities) {
  if (e instanceof XYItemEntity) {
    final XYItemEntity xyItem = (XYItemEntity) e;
    final int index = xyItem.getItem();
    final int series = xyItem.getSeriesIndex();
    Rectangle2D r = e.getArea().getBounds2D();
    checkPosition(r); // here you can check if the coordinates are inside your "box"
  }
}
```